# Mocking os.popen more than once or multiple times

Tags: python, mocking, popen

Below is my sample extract from main code

```
output = os.popen(". oraenv; echo $PATH; echo $ORACLE_BASE; echo $ORACLE_HOME").read()
print output
output1 = os.popen("some other command").read()
print output1
```

I am writing mock code for above, as read() function is used so the return value should be of type os.popen like below

```
@patch('os.popen', return_value=(os.popen('ls -la')))
def test_main_code(self, popen)
    some code......
```

As os.popen used two times, how can I modify my mock code to take return_value for output1 as well. As of now output1 is coming as blank.
I already tried side_effect to interate through value but values come as string not os.popen type.

```
popen.side_effect = ["os.popen('ls -la')","os.popen('ls -la')"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The side-effect option is that what you need but the trick is to use original `popen` to generate valid output each time it'll called:

```py
from os import popen

with mock.patch("os.popen", side_effect=lambda x: popen("ls -la")) as p:                                   
    output = os.popen(". oraenv; echo $PATH; echo $ORACLE_BASE; echo $ORACLE_HOME").read()
    print(output)
    output1 = os.popen("some other command").read()
    print(output1)
```

Comment: didnt understand output and output1 are part of original script, it cant be included in mock script.

Comment: getting error while trying like this "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

Comment: It's because your side-effect calls mocked function and not original one.

Comment: You could try to mock `read` as well with `@patch("os.popen", return_value=mock.Mock(read=lambda: popen("ls -la").read()))`.

Comment: thanks frost-nzcr4 for giving a try but its not working. In original script i am importing os so using os.popen. Now in mock script how to use popen from original script. I tried orig_script.os.popen but its giving max recursion error